# Bold part of a string / Add styles to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, variables, substring

I need to bold only the date in this string.

```
 <div class="foo"><p> Click here now and get by January 1st </p></div>
```

I was able to pull the date out and create a variable for it

```
 var fullMessage =  $('.foo p').text();
 var justTheDate = fullMessage.substring(fullMessage.indexOf('get by') + 7);
```

but I can't bold the substring/variable I created.  I was hoping something like this would work:

```
 $(justTheDate).css("font-weight","700");
```

Is this possible?

Comment: It is not clear from the way you are posing the question that you are dealing with a already rendered html page.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you:

```
var element = $('.foo p'),
    fullMessage =  element.text(),
    justTheDate = fullMessage.substring(fullMessage.indexOf('get by') + 7),
    boldIt = '<span style="font-weight: 700">' + justTheDate + '</span>',
    newHtml = fullMessage.replace(justTheDate, boldIt);

    element.html(newHtml)
```

[Fiddle demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/fux56tup/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you can't simply wrap the date part in a strong tag?

If the date is being populated dynamically, as through a variable, you could just have a placeholder of a span tag inside your p tag there with a class.

As `<span class="date"></span>`

Inject your date value into that tag, then simply apply css to this tag.

`span.date{font-weight: 600;}`.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the date is at the end, you could do create a span using jquery, (or regular javascript) and use append or appendChild to add it to the p tag.

```
var fullMessage =  $('.foo p')
var justTheDate = fullMessage.substring(fullMessage.text().indexOf('get by') + 7);
fullMessage.append('<span class="date">' + justTheDate + '</span>');
```

<strike>put it in a span and use a class to handle the css for that part.</strike>

```
<style>
    .date {
        font-weight: 700;
    }
</style>
<div class="foo"><p> Click here now and get by <span class="date">January 1st</span></p></div>
```

Comment: OP is asking HOW to add it.... Not adding it in HTML directly.

Comment: Believe me, I would have done that if I could!  The data is being returned to me that way.